# Grails 3.3.3 Using SQL Server Datasource and Hibernate 4.5.0.6

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, grails, gradle, mssql-jdbc

I cannot find a proper guide to include the jdbc driver for sql server in Grails 3.3.3. When I was in Grails 2.3.11, I was able to just place a jar in the lib directory and then I found the actual settings for Datasoure.groovy on the web so I copied and pasted and it worked.

Now for Grails 3.3.3 and the introduction of Gradle, I cannot find the proper resources to configure correctly. I'm on Java 8 so I prefer to use the latest drivers.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.6"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "pmtracker"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.7"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"

    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.4.0.jre8'

    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

application.yml

```
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
    username: sa
    password: password

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
        dbCreate: "update"
        url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PMTracker"

            #dbCreate: create-drop
            #url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

---
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: pmtracker
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:

    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
```

From what I understand, in Gradle you can include a certain line to link to a jdbc jar file in a repository right? I would prefer to do that over downloading the jar locally. You'll notice references to eclipse. I am using that as my IDE for developing grails projects. However I am running `grails run-app` from command line so I've isolated eclipse as not being the issue.

Error log when running grails run-app

```
C:\grails3projects\pmtracker>grails run-app
| Running application...
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'persistenceInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nes
ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could
not autowire method: public void org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePers
istenceContextInterceptor.setHibernateDatastores(org.grails.orm.hibernate.Abstra
ctHibernateDatastore[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.N
oSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hiberna
te.AbstractHibernateDatastore] found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hib
ernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(Sp
ringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:133)
        at pmtracker.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not au
towire method: public void org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePersistenc
eContextInterceptor.setHibernateDatastores(org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibe
rnateDatastore[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchB
eanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.Abs
tractHibernateDatastore] found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate
.AbstractHibernateDatastore]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowi
re candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.
java:661)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:331)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No q
ualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore] fou
nd for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]
: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this depend
ency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.
java:618)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished wi
th non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

EDIT:
So I thought the problem was my syntax for the sql jar. However when I comment out all of the hibernate lines in build.gradle, I can run the app fine. So obviously something with hibernate. I still want to use hibernate in my app though. Any way to fix this? hibernate came with grails so the fact that it doesn't work with sql jdbc is confusing.

Comment: Change dependency scope from testCompile to compile

Comment: As in `compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.4.0.jre8'`? That didn't work either.

Comment: Add the maven repository that hosts the driver to the repositories block

Comment: @npskirk How do I find that? I tried using this but it did not work `maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc" }`

Comment: All: I think I found a different cause for this issue. Please see edit.

Comment: Your post says `repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}`  Which does not contain `https://mvnrepository.com`

Comment: @npskirk Look at the comments. I added that to my file when you mentioned it but it did not work. Do you literally need me to add "https: // mvnrepository.com" or "https: // mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc"  ?

Comment: Add "mavenCentral()" or "jcenter()" to repositories closure

Comment: Just to update you all: It was a hibernate issue. I downgraded hibernate then upgraded. Everything started working. All in all it was a loss because I didn't like the extra work I had to do in Grails 3 when it comes to customizing views. So I just went back to Grails 2. Thanks for the help everyone.